# PermissionError-Task Scheduler

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

When I'm running a python script, addressed from a bat file, it works fine.
Trying to run it with Windows Task Scheduler, I'm getting:

> ```
>      with open('source.txt', '+w') as sour:
> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'source.txt'
> ```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The location of `source.txt` is not specified, which means that it's attempting to write it in the current directory. When you run your task from the scheduler, it is likely that you're doing so from a profile which runs it with `C:\Windows\System32` as the current directory. That location is protected, _as it is the system directory_. The fix is to specify the 'start in' directory for your task, or at the very least change directory in your script, to that which you expected. I would strongly recommend the former option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your current working directory is not writable to you when run from Task Scheduler. You can check that by simply doing

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

And the fix is pretty straightforward - simply use different location i.e. by using absolute path to your file or use `os.fchdir()` to change your dir.